# Autocalculcated field in pdf template

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm using SuiteCRM 7.8x and need to do autocalculated field when a contract based on pdf template is generated (just rigth in a code of a template).
For example, in module Contacts i have fields last name and first name - Andy Smith. And when i generate a contract i need the autocalculated field like:

```
$bean->p_fio_short_c = substr($bean->first_name,0,1) . '.' . $bean->last_name;
```

I can do it if i just create new field in a database for this calculating, but i don't want to do this way (irrational for database).

Comment: Do you mean you need that auto calculated field in the pdf?

Comment: @johnmccuk yes, in a pdf template

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to generate this pdf in for example in a logic hook, you could do it this way:

in your pdf template, put some manner of placeholder such as '%%auto-calc-field%%'.

and in your logic hook of choice:

```
$template = BeanFactory::getBean('AOS_PDF_Templates', 'some-id');
$value = $bean->p_fio_short_c = substr($bean->first_name,0,1) . '.' . $bean->last_name;
str_replace('%%auto-calc-field%%', $value, $template->description);
```

This would replace the placeholder text with the calculated value in the pdf template. You would generate the pdf and save it as required (in this case with mPDF), but tcpdf or similar could be used.

```
//Create the PDF
$pdf = new mPDF('en', 'A4', '', 'DejaVuSansCondensed', 15, 15, 16, 16, 8, 8);
$pdf->setAutoFont();
$pdf->SetHTMLHeader(html_entity_decode($template->pdfheader));
$pdf->SetHTMLFooter(html_entity_decode($template->pdffooter));
$pdf->writeHTML(html_entity_decode($template->description));

$pdf->Output('some/path/'. $bean->id .'.pdf'), 'F');
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! tell me, please which type of logic hooks should i use? and should i insert the second part of your code in right this logic hook too?

Comment: the logic hook for the specific Bean. So for example you want to generate this when you save an Account. Create a Account logic hook and place the code there.

Comment: As for the pdf generation, I cant remember what pdf library Suite uses. it may very well be mPDF, if not you may have to manually add that library.

Comment: i want this to be calculated just when i click in the Contact module "Generate PDF"

Comment: This solution wont work for that method. You would need to basically copy the code from the "Generate PDF" button and create your own button and insert the code above as required.